# application/pdf object opening in adobe reader but not in firefox browser tab asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firefox, pdf, http-headers, pdf-generation

I have my controller action method returning pdf file as

```
public FileContentResult GetPDF(string filename)
        {FileContentResult filecontent= new FileContentResult(Contents, "application/pdf");
               HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + filename);
               return filecontent;
}
```

here Contents is byte[] type.

If in my Adobe reader Edit->Preferences->Internet unchecked the "Display PDF in the browser" opens file but not with the filename in Adobe Reader. and if I checked that then it is not opening in Browser Tab for this I also tried with opening pdf file from a website it opened it browser tab so no issues with browser.

I need to be able to open pdf in browser tab with file name. can anybody help me because i find no solution after lot of search. Is iframe setting needed?

Answer (score 0):

try this if it works,

```
return File(filecontent,mimetype,filename);
```

or use `FileStreamResult` , idon't what exactly it does but try ,may works

regards,
kris